# Trying to pass php array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database, json

I have been searching the web like crazy for a day straight trying to figure out why my javascript code is not working. I am trying to pass an array from PHP to Javascript using JSON. After that i want to use it in other functions, thus kinda making the array or variable global. But i have been unable to get it to work, here is my code so far:

```
data = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('database.php', function(phpdata){
    // vad du vill göra här, allt retuneras i data-variabeln
    console.log(phpdata);
    data[0] = phpdata[0];
    console.log(data[0]);
  });

console.log(data);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the output of console.log(phpdata);?

Comment: is database.php echoing a json object? If so, are the headers correct on database.php?

Comment: it's ***asynchronous*** !

Comment: Please post the code to `database.php`, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

When `$.getJSON` is called, the JS engine will step parallely to the next instruction, which here is `console.log(data);`. This behaivour is caused to `$.getJson`'s asynchronuality.

Since the next step is calculated and executed in the very next millisecond, the webpage was not fully requested and data is still on its initialized value (`[]`).

What you can do:

Put all instructions that have to do something with your data in another function and call it on the anonymous function `function(phpdata) { ... }`.

Like this:

```
function dataLoaded(data) {
   // show data in dom elements
   // work with data, e.g. check for data["error"] = true or show the username from data["username"]
}

data = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Load JSON from server, wait for it and then work with it in dataLoaded(..)
  $.getJSON('database.php', function(phpdata){
      dataLoaded(phpdata);
  });
}
// this is wrong:
// console.log(data);
```

It is required that database.php will return an JSON array in the JSON data type. See `json_encode` and `header("CONTENT-TYPE: application/json")` on the php manual.

*Thanks to the comment for saying: failed case sensitive and data type.*

Comment: That should be `header('Content-Type: application/json')` (note that PHP instructions are case-sensitive).

Comment: Just one little thing: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: I get that point :-) Didn't talk about an object, just about "JSON array" what is not technically and definitionally right, too.

Comment: I tryed this, but i doesnt seem to work anyways =/.

Comment: Like this?: 

$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = [];
    function pass(arr)
    {
      var arr = [];
     $.ajax({
        url : 'database.php',
        dataType : "json",
        
        success : function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            arr = json;
            console.log(arr);
           return arr;
           
          
        }
    }
    
    );
    
    };
    console.log(arr);

Comment: If i use this:
array = [];
function callback(arr)
{
 array = phpdata;
};
 $.getJSON('database.php', function(phpdata){
    // vad du vill göra här, allt retuneras i data-variabeln
    callback(phpdata);
  });

It just says phpdata is not defined. Can i somehow make this array global so i can use it in my entire JS file?

Comment: You need to change `callback(arr) { array = phpdata; }; ` to `callback(arr) { array = arr; };` and REALLY work with arr only. And only in the callback function! Sorry, no way around since it is async

Answer (score 0):

What does database.php do? It should probably be outputting a JSON encoded string.

https://www.php.net/json_encode